# Can I move package.json into a folder?

Tags: html, reactjs

I would like to structure my react/vue/js/html project this way

```
-- demo
    -- project
        -- node_modules
        -- public
        -- src
        -- configs
            -- .gitignore
            -- package.json
            -- package-lock.json
            -- README.md
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you theoretically can. However by installing the dependencies you should explicitly say that you want `node_modules` to be installed in a different folder. One way of doing that is `npm --prefix ./myproject install ./myproject`

Comment: In your case, the directory, where you want to install the dependencies, should be the parent directory